Cetacean clicks: species recognition
I'm trying to undestand at which species could belong these clicks. I attach the Raven Pro view.
Could someone have an idea?

Hello! Welcome to Bioacoustics Stack Exchange! Please modify your Title and your question to add information so that our community can help you. Please give information regarding: Location where recording was made, time of year, any relevant information re: recording (towed array, etc). Please provide a link to the sound (perhaps saved on soundcloud) and other visualizations (spectrum, waveform, etc). Search other examples here using the [identification] or [species-identification] tags for help. Thank you and Good Luck!

Without being able to see detailes of the clicks and alternative processing, I guess it is safe to say, that we can exclude sperm whales (too high in frequency, too fast click repetition) and beaked whales (too fast click repetition). There is a interference pattern indicating clicks are generated close to surface suggesting some dolphin species. The clicks are most likely echolocation clicks as they show the typival amplitude variation of a scanning biosonar. Not sure if we can say more about the species from the spectrogram alone.
